# Opening slideshow images in prettyphoto

Tags: prettyphoto

I'd like to add a rel attribute to the links outputted by the function below. It's from a slideshow plugin I am trying to customize. I want slides/images to open up in prettyphoto when clicked. The plugin's links to images start like this: a style="" href="". I want them to start like this: a rel=prettyPhoto[pics] style="" href="" ....

Can somebody please help me out?

I want these images: http://www.publicnewshub.com/volvo-v40-revealed/
to open like this one: http://www.publicnewshub.com/jub-jub-co-accused-guilty/

```
loadEls: function () {
    function _(_, B) {
        var $ = new RegExp("\\[a((.*?)\\[\\/a\\]", "gi"),
            A = _.match($);
        $J.$A(A).j14(function (D) {
            if (B.textEffect == "fixed" && (new RegExp("href", "gi")).test(D)) {
                var A = D + "",
                    C = new RegExp('^.*?href=\\"([^\\"]+)\\".*$', "gi");
                href = D.replace(C, "$1");
                if ((new RegExp("onclick", "gi")).test(A)) {
                    C = new RegExp('onclick=\\"([^\\"]+)\\"', "gi");
                    A = A.replace(C, "onclick=\"$1;document.location.href='" + href + "';\"");
                    A = A.replace($, "<a $1>$2</a>");
                } else {
                    A = A.replace($, "<a $1 onclick=\"document.location.href='" + href + "';\">$2</a>");
                }
            } else {
                return A = D.replace($, "<a $1>$2</a>");
            }
            _ = _.split(D).join(A);
        });
        return _;
```